# VIsual database tool for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

It there a visual db editor (similar to Navicat - http://www.navicat.com/products) that is designed to work with rails migrations and other rails-like approaches to models?

Specifically, I would like a graphical tool that can aid in the creation and maintenance of rails models/migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a visual tool to actually edit or design migrations. But there is one to draw a graph of an existing setup. It includes `has_many` relationships which are defined in the model. It is called Rails ERD (Entity-Relationship Diagrams for Ruby on Rails):

http://rails-erd.rubyforge.org/